# How to show csv data point in Arcgis

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geoprocessing, csv

I have sought and tried many tutorials and documents without success. I have arcgis desktop 10.2.2 installed. I have added a US map as a layer. Then I do the following hoping to display all (2000+) data points on the map as another layer.

Add data > select my csv (which contains 2000+ rows each with a longitude and latitude > display data > OK.

I am able to see all the data imported by right-click > open. But when I did the above sequence of selections, there is only one single dot displayed.

Example:

```
name class lat  lon
Stony 1 35.773444   -78.6305752
fowler zak 0 38.82349688    -77.61919194
```

Comment: Check your spatial reference, the lat/long data may be in a different format than your US layer. Perhaps the points are being displayed in different units or the zoom level is too high.

Comment: Sorry I am very new to arcgis, how do I check/change spatial reference?

Comment: Right click your layer -> properties -> 'source' tab, look at the coordinate system type. Use the Project tool to match your x/y event layer to the coordinate system of your US layer.

Comment: Adding to the above, you're likely only 'seeing' one dot because relative to the whole map, your points are very close to each other. If you zoomed in to them closely, you'll likely see them all. Lat long is in degrees, such as 41N 87W. The coordinate system for your US layer is probably in meters or feet. So your lat/long data is displaying 41 ft or meters north, 87 west of the US layers 0,0 starting point. Data in the US layer is probably in the hundreds of thousands, even millions, of feet or meters.

Comment: Can you show a few rows as an example of what you've got in the table. Without knowing *exactly* how the coordinate is specified we can't help get the locations *exact*. CSV (and Excel) can be a little unstable, it might work in your favor to import to DBF/personal (Access) database table. Esri can also 'have a cow' about field names/header row - it should not contain spaces, punctuation and no repeats.

Comment: I have followed the suggestions and it seemed changing all the layer's coordinate system into the same one works. The example data is added. My next step is to draw those coordinate green when the class == 1 and red when class == 2. Could someone give me some material I can learn to do that? Thanks.